# using an associated field name in slug_candidates in friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

Is it possible to use a association in my slug_candidates method?

for example, where my model belongs_to :car

```
def slug_candidates
    [
      [car.owner, :horsepower, "horsepower"],
      [car.owner, car.nickname, :horsepower, "horsepower"]
    ]
end
```

right now it returns

**NoMethodError: undefined method `owner' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: Where do you define this method? Please provide code of the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I assume this is a method defined in an ActiveRecord model.*

It's because one of the records you are using does not have a `car` (ie. it is `nil`).

So when you do `car.owner` on that specific record (there may be more than one btw) are essentially trying to call the method `owner` on `nil` (ie. `nil.owner`), therefore the error.

Comment: Can't believe i missed this. in my local app I have a lot of old records where it was possible to have some records with an invalid association. thanks.