# defining slug candidates from associated db with friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I have an **Application.rb** that

```
belongs_to :company
```

and the **Company.rb** can

```
has_many :applications
```

I've set up friendly_id on the Company model but also want it on my application. But the Application doesn't store what I want as slug_candidates. I want slug candidates to be taken from the Company the application belongs to.

This is my **Applicatio.rb**

```
extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :history]

def slug_candidates
 [
  :intern_type,
  [:intern_type, Company.city]
 ]
end
```

how would I set it up so it gets that it should take it from the Company?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to do in Application model,

```
def slug_candidates
  [
    :intern_type,
    [:intern_type, company.city]
  ]
end
```

I think that this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271593/using-an-associated-field-name-in-slug-candidates-in-friendly-id) has a similar issue.

Hope this helps!